# Is it possible to have a REST url parameter with an ampersand?

Tags: c#, .net, rest

Using the System.ServiceModel libraries for routing, I have a REST service with a simple template that looks like

> "{searchTerm}?opt={someSearchOpt}

So the call would look like:

> http://myhost.contoso.com/searchapi/river%20expeditions

to search for the phrase "river expeditions" with no options.

This simply accepts a search phrase and returns results. It works just fine. However, if searching for a phrase that contains a literal ampersand, such as "Lewis&Clark", i tried the obvious of url encoding the ampersand

> Lewis%26Clark

but even so the request is never even routed, but the server immediately returns a 400 Bad Request. It is clear that it is being interpreted as a query string delimiter, and makes the request invalid since this particular template is expecting a url parameter and has no preceeding '?' delimiter.

Since these search phrases may have other restricted characters, they are expected to by url encoded by the client, and when they are successfully routed, the REST api calls HttpUtility.UrlDecode on the parameter. So my question is really if there is some technique to getting a url encoded ampersand correctly routed as a rest url parameter and not pre-emptively interpreted and rejected as a query string delimiter?

Update: For the record, if the search term were expected as a query string parameter (not a url parameter), sending *Lewis%26Clark* works fine. For example

> http://myhost.contoso.com/searchapi?searchTerm=lewis%26clark

So to clarify, I am looking to get the same result when using a url parameter in a REST template.

Comment: +1. Just wait until you need to encode slashes... Sysmem.Uri "helpfully" unescapes them all without being asked as a security "feature".

Comment: There is no query string in your sample... Not sure if I'm missing something...

Comment: @alexei ...exactly the point...it is a REST api, and therefore the search term is a url parameter, not a query string parameter...a more common example is `http://myhost.contoso.com/restapi/customer/3` where "3" is a url parameter. In my example, the "opt" query string param is optional and can be left out.

Comment: I see what you mean... Consider reading/updating title of your question than... Also I don't think it is good idea to pass arbitrary string as part of the path (check  [Uri RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) for what is not allowed in path).

Comment: @alexei Thanks for pointing out the title was vague. I updated it. As far as the rest of your answer, I guess I am bumping up against the standards. Part of that is the way the restful uri's push the limits. Imagine I had a bookstore service that let me look up stock by store name: `/bookstore/fiction/instock?title=encoded%20title` ....that would be easy to use, but fail if 'bookstore' was 'barnes&noble' !  Anyways...your response is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359305/mvc-web-api-routing-fails-when-url-contains-encoded-ampersand) thread has a similar question\solution.

As mentioned in the answer from the above link, I would avoid url encodeding characters in the uri and instead put those in the query string portion.

Comment: I second the motion to avoid url-encoded characters in the path and instead stick them in the query.

Comment: @TimothyShields I agree...although hindsight is 20/20. The API was already published and made public, and the ampersand-containing search term was a corner case that came out only after QA testing and release.