# Using a colon in a URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, urlencode

I'm attempting to pass a time value as a string, however the encoding for the `:` colon is not working. It's displaying as `%3a` in the URL (`/Edit/9%3a45`), but when clicked on, the page says

> A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:)

What can I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC WEB API routing fails when url contains encoded ampersand](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359305/mvc-web-api-routing-fails-when-url-contains-encoded-ampersand)

Comment: Due to security reasons asp.net is treating this as an xss attack. You could send it via http request body.

Comment: what is the problem with HHMMss ?

Answer (score -1):

Transfer it using Session:

```
Session["DateValue"]=yourDateTime;
```

How to take it after that:

```
if(Session["DateValue"] != null)
{
    DateTime time = (DateTime)Session["DateValue"];
}
```

You can check this tutorial [Tutorial](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-create-and-access-447ada98)

Comment: This post does not answer the question.