# WebApi 2 GET has special character in parameter

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

My problem comes when I **call a webapi2 GET** with a string parameter that has **special char** (with normal character all works correctly).

**AngularJs**

```
this.getByContactValue = function (contactValue) {   
        return $http.get("/api/subjects/"+ contactValue+ "/ContactValue" );
    }
```

**c#**

```
[Route("api/subjects/{contactValue}/ContactValue")]
public IEnumerable<Subject> GetByContactValue(string contactValue)
{
    return repository.GetByContactValue(contactValue);
}
```

The response is **404 error**.
I tried also to modify the request in this way

```
this.getByContactValue = function (contactValue) {
        var request = $http({
            method: "get",
            url: "/api/subjects/ContactValue", //modified the route in c# controller
            data: contactValue
        });
        return request;
    }
```

But the error is the same.

Which is the best way to call the webapi?

Comment: The best way is to pass the parameters in either querystring or the form. can you please provide the data for which the error is occuring?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359305/mvc-web-api-routing-fails-when-url-contains-encoded-ampersand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I solved in this way

```
[Route("api/subjects/ContactValue")]
public IEnumerable<Subject> GetByContactValue([FromUri]string contactValue)
{                                 
    return repository.GetByContactValue(contactValue);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You've to pass data in query strings as

```
$http({
    url: "/api/subjects/ContactValue", 
    method: "GET",
    params: {contactValue: contactValue}
 });
```

Update your action

```
[Route("api/subjects/ContactValue?contactValue={contactValue}")]
public IEnumerable<Subject> GetByContactValue(string contactValue)
{
    return repository.GetByContactValue(contactValue);
}
```

Comment: In this way i receive this error  - `The route template cannot start with a '/' or '~' character and it cannot contain a '?' character.` Have I to specify the value of the parameter in the controller ?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to use encodeURI or **encodeURIComponent**, it'll Encode data in url.

**Ts-**

```
   let bg= encodeURIComponent(contactValue);
   return AuthAxios.get(`${APINAME}?bg=${bg}`);
```

**API**

```
    [HttpGet(nameof(GetBgList))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetBgList(string bg)
    {
        return Ok(MessageAlert.DataFound(await _bgService.GetBgList(bg)));
    }
```